# JS Object strange behaviour when trying access Loopback related model query

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I am working with the Loopback Framework, doing a web project.
But I think that the question that I am exposing here has less to do with this, but with general Javascript / Node.JS knowledge.

At one part of the code, I am doing:

```
roleMapping.find({
        where: {
            principalType: 'USER',
            principalId: context.principals[0].id
        },
        include: 'role'
    }, function(err, roles){
        console.log(roles[0]);
        for (var i in roles)
        {
            if (roles[i].role.name === 'teamLeader' &&
                roles[i].groupId === context.modelId)
            {
                cb(null,true);
            }else {
                cb(null,false);
            }
        }
});
```

Ok with this, but it fails when trying to compare `roles[i].role.name`.
So, I went logging what the `roles[i]` object contained.

```
    { groupId: 1,
  id: 3,
  principalType: 'USER',
  principalId: 1,
  roleId: 2,
  role: 
   { id: 2,
     name: 'teamLeader',
     description: 'The leader(s) of a team',
     created: null,
     modified: null } }
```

Ok, nothing wrong, but it still fails, so I tried to print just the `role` property. And to my surprise:

```
{ [Function]
  update: [Function],
  destroy: [Function],
  create: [Function],
  build: [Function],
  _targetClass: 'Role' }
```

So, the `role` property seems to be some sort of function? But how it was been correctly printed before?

Eventually, lost in my frustration I tried `var role = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(roles[i]));`

And then I could access every property of the object normally, but this is not clean nor normal.

This blew my mind for the first time in years of JS programming (sort of amateurish though), and I would be pleased if someone could clarify this to me. Thanks

EDIT: It seems that it is specific to this Framework, so I'm changing title to help community.

Comment: Can you show us the code you used to print them?

Comment: `console.log(roles[i]);` printing whole object ok, and `console.log(roles[i].role)` printing the weird thing.

Comment: I think I've seen mongodb doing similar weird things. Does `roles[i]` have a `.toJSON` method?

Comment: Yeah it looks like you need to extract the actual value (your object) somehow. It also looks like the logged object might in fact be a function. Does `roles[i]()` return anything?

Comment: Thay may have something to do with the behaviour of the `for (... in ...)` loop. You could try using `for (var i = 0, length = roles.length; i < length; i++) { <your code here> }` instead. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: Yes it does! `roles[i].toJSON()` prints the same as the first `console.log(roles[i]);` But it's no MongoDB, I am using MySQL as the data backend, but maybe Loopback is trying to emulate some MongoDB?

Comment: @Jan no, it crashes with `Object [object Object] has no method '0'`

Comment: would like to link this question to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51226178/1870331) too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just found [issue 1425](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1425) which links to the following [docs](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Include+filter#Includefilter-Accessincludedobjects):

> With Node.js API, you need to call `toJSON()` to convert the returned model instance with related items into a plain JSON object
>
> Please note the relation properties […] points to a JavaScript *function* for the relation method.

So it seems you have to use

```
for (var i=0; i<roles.length; i++) {
    var x = roles[i].toJSON();
    cb(null, x.role.name === 'teamLeader'
             && x.groupId === context.modelId);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I have the same tab open right now, but I missed that section.
Thanks, and sorry ;)

Comment: http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Include+filter#Includefilter-Accessincludedobjects